# Delete arrow from google map

Tags: google-maps

Hello friends i trying to set `Google Map` as a background of the web page like **[this](http://www.apartmentlist.com/home)**
. I m noticing in this site that the map which is used by this site has no arrows and plus minus icons on it. i don't know how to get this kind of code of `Google Map`. I trying to do the same but there on google map page no option to delete these features

Please help me

any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's the demo code to do the map that you want. visit [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) you will have to change the parameters such as center and zoom level. then you can achieve the map as you have shown in the question. for documentation plz refer [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HTML5)

Comment: thanks for help @NejiHyuga. i am confused and not understand .. will you plz elaborate .. sorry for asking more

Comment: well you can find tutorials there. there are also examples, you can check more demos with its source code visit http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_simple_v3 there are the parameters center and zoom while initializing map object, change that to focus on the region you want to and also zoom level

Answer (score 1):

There are certain options for the map that you can disable when initializing your map. You can find a list of these map options in Google Maps API Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

To get just a bare map, you'll probably have to do something like this for your map options:

```
var myOptions = {
  zoom: (specify zoom level),
  center: (your map's center),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
  draggable: false,
  overviewMapControl: false, 
  panControl: false,
  scrollwheel: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  zoomControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false
}
```